# Problem with bpy.ops.object.origin_set

Tags: python, scripting

I wrote a script that is attached to a button in the addon. Works perfectly, up to the code line, where is bpy.ops.object.origin_set (type = 'ORIGIN_CENTER_OF_VOLUME'). The previous command works without problems, but here the transfer of origin to the center don't work, the object switches to edit mode. The previous command that moves the cursor to the center works without a problem.
How to solve this problem ?
I would be very grateful for your help.

```
class ImportSTL(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Import STL"""
    bl_idname = "object.import_stl"
    bl_label = "Import STL"

    def execute(self, context):
        stl_path = bpy.path.abspath(bpy.context.scene.stl_path)
        bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath=stl_path)
        try:
            ob_new = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
            for f in ob_new.data.polygons:
                f.use_smooth = True
            for b in ob_new.data.polygons:
                bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()   
                bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='TOGGLE')                
                bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(use_extend=False, use_expand=False, type='FACE')
                bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='TOGGLE')    
                bpy.ops.mesh.tris_convert_to_quads()
                bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_selected()
                bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CENTER_OF_VOLUME')
```

Greets

Comment: `bpy.ops.object.origin_set` is an object mode operator.  Instead of using TOGGLE would SELECT_ALL and set the mode to EDIT, then object.  (or use bmesh)  Why the loop over faces?

Comment: I think I followed your instructions. conversion to quads has stopped working, but after all, it stays in object mode. I don't know how to use Bmesh