# Why is object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CURSOR') not working?

Tags: python, scripting, origin

```
def execute(self, context):
    stl_path = bpy.path.abspath(bpy.context.scene.stl_path)
    bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath=stl_path)
    try:
        ob_new = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
        for f in ob_new.data.polygons:
            f.use_smooth = True
        for b in ob_new.data.polygons:
            bpy.context.space_data.show_textured_solid = True
            bpy.context.object.show_transparent = True
            bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'
            bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()   
            bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='TOGGLE')                
            bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(use_extend=False, use_expand=False, type='FACE')
            bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='TOGGLE')    
            bpy.ops.mesh.tris_convert_to_quads()
            bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_selected()
            bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type = 'ORIGIN_CURSOR')
```

Everything is working well, until I use `origin_set`. Maybe I should go to object mode, after converting mesh to quads. 
But when I'm adding `bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()` after `tris_convert_to_quads` Blender is freezing. Without this last command, everything is working, also snapping cursor to selected.

---

Ok, I changed script.

```
def execute(self, context):
    stl_path = bpy.path.abspath(bpy.context.scene.stl_path)
    bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath=stl_path)
    try:
        ob_new = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
        for f in ob_new.data.polygons:
            f.use_smooth = True
            bpy.context.object.show_transparent = True
            bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'
            bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
            bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='TOGGLE')                
            bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(use_extend=False, use_expand=False, type='FACE')
            bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='TOGGLE')    
            bpy.ops.mesh.tris_convert_to_quads()
            bpy.ops.mesh.faces_shade_smooth()
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
            bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='TOGGLE')
```

to this line everything is ok, and script is ends in object mode.
but If I add this line
                bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CENTER_OF_MASS')

I have msg in console, that I must be in object mode.
If i add this command
                bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
Blender is switching off.

Comment: Any error message in the console? Also please add what your actual goal is.

Comment: You can't set the origin in edit mode.

Comment: Using try and catch will remove seeing error messages in console.

Comment: Also please don't ask same question again [closed prior](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170840/problem-with-bpy-ops-object-origin-set?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. To set object origin, you must be in object mode. You can also try using `bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')` to change to object mode.

Comment: Ok, I added this bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT'), after converting to quads, and Blender freezes again :-(  When I added it after snap cursor to select, it happened the same

Comment: In console I have only information that, import finished in 1.2480 sec. My goal is that, that I have button, that import stl, converting to quads, changing origin to volume, and after it, is moving object with new origin, to 0,0,0

Comment: @Neuroup I have a fix for blender freezing. Before running the script, go to 'window' and click 'toggle system console'. Rerun the script. If blender freezes, switch to the console and press 'q' to terminate the operation. In my experience, this results in the desired output many times.

Comment: I started the system console as you wrote. When Blender crashed, I pressed the q key in the console (few times). Unfortunately, it did nothing. I just have a message that Import Finished in 1.2490 sec.